# Xamarin find in files with regex modifiers

Tags: regex, visual-studio, xamarin-studio

Using the Find in Files feature in Xamarin Studio (`Command + Shift + F`) I want to search for this regex:

`(^\s*[\/]{2}.*?[;,]$)`

with the modifiers `gm`

Is it possible to use modifiers here? What about in Visual Studio?

Comment: These are the modifiers that are usually enabled by default in editors. `/g` must be represented with `Replace all` button or something like that. If your regex does not work, use inline version of `/m` - `(?m)` at the beginning of the pattern. One note about VS: `\s` does not match a `\r` there. And a general note: no need to escape `/` here.

Comment: Why are you searching for a regex, don't you already have one ?

Comment: @sln you know what I meant :)

Comment: Visual Studio has checkboxes for options.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew can you give me a full example of the inline version please?

Comment: Look up Dot-Net regex syntax, it's the same.

Comment: Well, `(?m)^\s*/{2}.*[;,]$`. Or `(?m)^[\t\p{Zs}]*/{2}.*[;,]$`

Comment: It's an odd combination `(?m)^\s*` can span lines, did you intend for all on single line?

Comment: I'm searching for commented out code, so many lines. @WiktorStribiżew that worked, if you post it I'll accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the global modifier `/g`, you should look for a `Replace all` button or something like that. The multiline modifier can be replaced with its inline counterpart `(?m)` that is usually placed at the start of the pattern.

You may use

```
(?m)^\s*/{2}.*[;,]$
^^^^    ^    ^
```

Or - in case you want to explicitly match horizontal whitespace after the line start:

```
(?m)^[\t\p{Zs}]*/{2}.*[;,]$
     ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Note I turned the lazy quantifier to the greedy one (`.*?` -> `.*`) because you want to match a colon or a comma at the end of the line, so a greedy quantifier is more logical to use here.

And `/` does not have to be escaped here as the modifiers are not part of the regex here (and has no regex delimiters, `/` is often used as a regex delimiter, in JS, PHP, Perl, etc.)